# using strongly typed datasets with textboxes on web forms

Tags: asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I would like to use a strongly typed dataset with textboxes on a web form. How can i do this?
Cheers
Mick

Comment: You need to give more information. What are you trying to do with the DataSet and the textbox. Are you using only one textbox? Is there more thabn one row in the DataSet?

Comment: Sorry about that, i will always be returning only one row and at the moment there are eight textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

i am really confused about the question, but if you are using linq, you can query the DB and then call `Singleordefault()` function to return single record, then you just simply can do like this

```
TextBox1.Text = SingleRecordQuery().YourDBField;
```

hope this helps.